# ArcGIS Resample Tool Crashes with "Not implemented"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-999999, resampling

I'm trying to run the `Resample` GP tool with a mosaic dataset as an input. The mosaic dataset contains a raster for Peru, the Democratic Republic of Congo, and Indonesia. Each raster is in WGS84, which is projected to Web Mercator within the Mosaic Dataset. Cell size for each is 0.00025 degrees.

Each raster has a raster function applied to transform its value from Julian day (i.e. 1 - 366) to year + Julian day (1/1/2015 becomes 15001).

I'm running `resample` using the `MAJORITY` option, with output pixels at 55m x 55m in WGS 84 Web Mercator. Eight minutes into the process, it crashes with the classic `Error 999999: Error executing function`, followed by `Not implemented` and `Failed to execute (Resample)`.

I'm used to error `999999`, but have never seen `Not Implemented`. Is there an issue with my inputs? Or is this kind of operation even possible with a raster of this size and pixel depth? What workarounds are available?

Comment: Can you try export the mosaic dataset as a single raster, perhaps there's one tile that has 0 pixels that's making it fall over or a raster link that's broken... if you make a single IMG or TIFF from the mosaic dataset it might help... or project to your output coordinate system then resample to 55 metre pixels; it could be the transformation between the two is causing problems. Unfortunately the error message is (as usual) not very helpful so I'm clutching for straws.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @MichaelMiles-Stimson. I'm writing the raster to .tif now-- will let you know what happens when I try to resample it. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson successfully exported to a local .tiff file and resampling succeeded. Must be some bug with the Mosaic Dataset stuff. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's good to know. Perhaps you could put together your experiences and detail your workflow as an answer to your own question for future users; as you say it's probably a bug so it's quite likely that someone else will be searching for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Michael Miles-Stimson's recommendation, I employed the following workaround:

1. Export mosaic dataset to TIFF (right click on it in ArcCatalog >> Export >> Raster to Different Format)
2. Ran the `Resample` tool on this dataset, which gave the expected output.